# Sharp corners appear to be rounded at smaller size

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo, optical-illusion

Has anyone seen this optical illusion of sharp corners appearing to be rounded when scaling the graphic down? Is there a way to compensate for it, like there is for the "bone effect"?

In this example, the top right corner of the logo is perfectly sharp, yet when it's scaled down it appears rounded. Also, the rest of the sharp corners appear to be slightly rounded too.

[image]

Comment: I don't see it. Sure, it's a bit fuzzy-edged when you zoom in because we're looking at a raster image, but I'm not seeing any 'optical illusion'.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. I don't see any rounded corners or optical illusion either. However, it's usual when designing a logo to be aware that it should look good at large or small scales. Generally you'd do that by simplifying a design so that there is no fine detail that will disappear or blur to oblivion when reduced in size. In your example, the notch and the serif are a bit too small. Make them bigger and more obvious.

Comment: yeah I see it.. but it's just the nature of raster (or pixel displays) at smaller sizes. Anti-aliasing can't help by make *some* angles appear more "fuzzy" and round. Not much you can do about it other than increasing angles. -- I mean the inner curve of the arcs looks way more straight when reduced as well.

Comment: @Scott Thanks, I think that makes a lot of sense.